# How to call instance method inside class using Swift

Tags: swift

I am having  an issue with calling an instance method within the class itself. If someone can provide me some insight it would be greatly appreciated.
My current code looks like this:

```
class Rect
{
func printthis() -> String {
    return "this is working or what"
}

var toPrint:String = self.printthis()

}
```

The error I am getting in Xcode is: Use of unresolved identifier 'self'.

What am I missing here?

Comment: never seen swift, but I'm guessing that it has to be a static method if you're assigning to a class variable.

Comment: It's not a class variable, it's an instance variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance of a class is not initialized and able to be referenced (even as 'self') until all of its variables have been assigned values.

An option that may work for you is to declare your variable as an implicitly-unwrapped optional, which is assigned nil by default. Then in the class's init method, since all of the variables have been assigned values, you are able to start calling methods on your instance.

```
class Rect {
    var toPrint: String!

    init() {
        toPrint = printthis()
    }

    printthis() -> String {
        return "this will work"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't call an instance method without an instance. The `class` is merely the template for instances. So i don't what you are trying to do here...

But the answer is *no*, you cannot call an instance method form the class definition because there is no instance yet.

---

Perhaps you want to delcare a *class* method and use that to set an instance variable on creation? If so, you might do that like this:

```
class Rect {
    class func printthis() -> String {
        return "this is working or what"
    }

    var toPrint:String

    init() {
        toPrint = Rect.printthis()
    }
}

var r = Rect()
println(r.toPrint) //-> this is working or what
```

Comment: Had a similar question and based on your answer tried assigning the class method directly to the property without the 'init()' code and it works: 'var toPrint: String = Rect.printthis()'.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that swift is strict about initing all properties.
you may as a workaround

```
class Rect
{
    func printthis() -> String {
        return "this is working or what"
    }

    var toPrint:String = ""

    init() {
        toPrint = printthis()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian as well for taking the time to respond to my question!